# How to retrieve an image from a database using imageid in the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

Saving the image in a web directory and storing the URL in the database using this approach, I stored the image URL in the database. Based on that image id (I need to pass this image id to the controller from an Ajax call). I need to retrieve the image.

I got the image id using a jQuery template, so I have passed that image id to the controller. What should I write in the controller, filepathresult or fileresult? Or is there another approach?

Answer (score 0):

OK, you're a bit confused.

You have the actual image file, `file.jpg` and you have the physical path to the file, `D:\some\path\to\file.jpg`.

You have the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) path to the file and a surrogate identity (your id).

- id:  1337  (some random number)
- URL:  ????

First question:

You say you're storing the URL. Is it really the complete URL? Is it just a partial path to the image? Is the path from the root of the website or the root of the application? Is it just a partial physical path?

Second question:

What are you actually trying to do?

Do you just want to get the full path to the image? Why do you need Ajax to do this, if you already have the id? You might want to rethink how you're storing the images if any performance needs to come out of this.

Once an image gets a new identity, it often makes sense to use that new identity everywhere; you might ought to consider copy/rename the file for the new identity after it's uploaded (and possibly save the old filename for record keeping purposes). If you need to keep the file names (more or less) as-is, however, it'd be better to provide the ability to grab the URLs for a whole set of ids rather than to individually make an Ajax request id-by-id.

Comment: yeah, i have id ,candidateid and url in database. based on candidate id, i need to retrieve image for that particular candidate. i got candidate id, so haved passed this to controller. now in that controller what should i write.` [HttpPost] 
        public JsonResult GetPhotos(int CPId)
     {
         var cabin = Reposi.GetPhotos(CPId);  
         return Json(cabin,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }`      i got simply url.

Comment: that url was, jus example www.abc.com/images/xyz.jpg.. in my page again i am getting this url only

Answer (score 0):

If you request a resource (AKA navigate to a [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator)) that has a physical file, [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) is going to serve it directly (that is, if you ask for `www.mysite.com/Images/Image3.jpg` IIS is going to serve it directly). I really don't understand exactly what you are doing, but if you mean that you get the associated URL for an image using an Ajax call to an MVC controller with the id of the image, you could do several things.

1. You could simply return the URL and use JavaScript code to create an image tag with that URL and inserting it in the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model).
2. You could return a view like <img src="{yoururl}" /> and insert it in the DOM using JavaScript.
3. You could store the images on the database directly and use the File method to return the image bits indicating the correct [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) type.

Comment: but i am getting same url path in my page when i write controller like this`[HttpPost] public JsonResult GetPhotos(int CPId) { var cabin = Reposi.GetPhotos(CPId); return Json(cabin,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); }`